# More generic tool than TeXdoc?

Tags: documentation, comments, texdoc

I'm wondering if there is a more generic tool than TeXdoc to browse (and generate) documentation. With TeXdoc, one retrieves (as far as I know) the documentation `.pdf` of the package. This requires that the developer generates such `.pdf` and furthermore some of these files are not structured to find the specifications for a macro easily.

Java however has a specific syntax to document methods (macros in LaTeX) such that an IDE can show documentation on the fly and web/pdf documentation can be generated automatically based on the javadoc annotations.

Is there a package/tool to document a package one has developed such that other programs (IDE's, browsers) can use this information?

Comment: You can also [read books](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27636/34551) with `texdoc` You should probably also have a look at [`clsguide`](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/clsguide.pdf). I think a package is devoted to the writing of documentation, but cannot find its name.

Comment: You mean the `doc` package?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: not exactly. The documentation should be placed *in the same file* as where the macros are defined. And then a postprocessor can generate documentation.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Look up `dtx`/`doc`. Literate programming was invented for TeX.