# Where to find LaTeX commands source code?

Tags: documentation, sourcecode

I would like to know where can I find the definition of an original command. That is, let's say I want to redefine the command `\ref` so when I type it, instead of showing just the number of the label of input, also says 'figure' or 'table' or whatever the `\label` refers to (This may be a silly example but try to see my point).

Well, I imagine how I could *modify* `\ref` given the code, but as I don't have deep knowledge of LaTeX, or I am lazy, I can't figure how to *renew it* out of thin air.

So, is there anywhere one may have a look at the original code and well change this and that to work this sort of situations out?

Thanks to everyone for your attention.

Comment: (For the silly example the `cleveref` package exists. `hyperref` also defines a few `ref` commands for this purpose.) For the definition of `\ref`, you can take a look at [`latex.ltx`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). But any package can overwrite this itself so you may be better off using `\show`/`\meaning` and/or `latexdef` (see [tag:texdef]).

Comment: On the specific 'auto-magic' label/ref case, see package `cleveref` (`\cref`) and facilities in the `hyperref` package (`\autoref`).

Comment: One of the amazing features of LaTeX is that there are hundreds of packages providing facilities for *many* tasks; if you need something not really very special, it's likely that somebody has already solved the problem and issued a package for it.

Comment: For the example you mention, you would need to redefine *both* `\label` and `\ref`. The original LateX code can be found in pretty-printed form in source2e.pdf (chapter 53). The source for that chapter is ltxref.dtx.

Comment: Perhaps see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) or [Where can I find an online manual for low-level LaTeX commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22883/5764)

Comment: For the raw definition (no documentation), there is always the `texdef` tool: `texdef -t latex \ref`.  As for redefining it, simply `\renewcommand` to a copy of the definition in your preamble and make your necessary changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can go about solving this problem, mostly depending on how much detail you would like.

Getting the raw code definition of any command is trivial; there is a TeX primitive `\meaning`, which will expand to the current one-level expansion of the macro (that is, it will not attempt to expand those macros inside of it).  If you are using a complicated package setup or if the definition of the macro is changing, this is the most reliable way to go. Otherwise, you can save some time with the `texdef` Perl script:

```
$ texdef -t latex large

\large:
\long macro:->\@setfontsize \large \@xiipt {14}
```

Note that this only parses the output of TeX as seen below, but it can be a huge timesaver for simple queries.

[image: meaning output]

See its `man` or `info` page for documentation on the tool, or use `texdoc texdef`, which brings us to the next level.

With TeX being a typesetting language, it just so happens that many package authors/teams are also *very* good, thorough writers.
The `texdoc` tool will take its argument and search all of the documentation that is available to it for your term.
Now, it doesn't do a search in *depth* but in *breadth*; it will not search the *contents* of all the documentation available to it.
(That would take forever!)
Most of my needs are met with `texdoc`; normally you can provide the package name that your command belongs to and violà: your documentation opens in your default reader.

The documentation for the LaTeX kernel is also available with `texdoc source2e` (and a pared-down, unfinished `macros2e`); as for the detail of this documentation—well—it's turtles all the way down.
See `man texdoc`, `info texdoc`, and—you guessed it—`texdoc texdoc` for more information on this tool.

If `texdoc` yet does not satisfy you, then the last resorts are printed books and Google, where [printed books](http://latex-project.org/guides/books.html) generally only compile information already available for free.