# What are good advanced LaTeX books?

Tags: documentation, big-list, books

I've been using LaTeX for about 3 months, and I'm hooked. My background is programming, so for the basic, google is sufficient. I did some research on amazon.com and found these two books with many positive feedback:
[LaTeX-Companion-Techniques-Computer-Typesetting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996)
[Guide to LaTeX (4th Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321173856)

However, most of people said they are more like references than a real book. And if they really are, then I think I'd rather look up at CTAN. What I'm looking for is a book that can teach me how to program in LaTeX, for example:

1. Write my own package
2. Create animation
3. Create and using macro in LaTeX
   ....

I know there are many options around, however to pick the right one is not an easy task. Any advice or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a book which covers points 1 and 2. Also note it's 'LaTeX' not 'Latex' (or 'LaTex' or 'latex', but `latex` is the compiler.)

Comment: For 1. have a look at `clsguide` on CTAN.

Comment: …and also [`dtxtut`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut).

Comment: @Martin: the compiler is `pdftex`, not `latex`

Comment: @Herbert: Ok, `latex` is a symlink to `pdftex`. Close enough ;-)

Comment: @Martin: I wonder if you have a chance to have a look at those two titles I mentioned above? If you did, could you give me some feedback about them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Chan: They are both very good books and the first one contains good information on package writing (if I remember correctly). If you have access to them (check your local library) then you should really try to read them.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I found them in my school library ^_^ Happy!

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A personal list of list for heavy LaTeX users:

- More Math into LaTeX, 4ed. (easier)
- A Guide To LaTeX, 4ed.
- Digital Typography Using LaTeX. Springer.

More advanced:

- The LaTeX Companion, 2ed.
- The LaTeX Graphics Companion, 2ed.

And more: Many documents of LaTeX packages (user-level).

---

A personal useful book list for macro writers:

- TeXbook.
- [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic). (free eBook)

A personal useful (package) documentation list for package and class writers, general purpose:

- clsguide: LaTeX2e for class and package writers.
- source2e: Documented source code of LaTeX kernel.
- classes: Documented source code of LaTeX standard classes.
- macros2e: Martin's useful manual for LaTeX internal macros. (c.f. source2e)
- eTeX's manual.
- etoolbox: a useful toolbox of eTeX. For modern packages it is really useful.
- keyval: Support for key-value interface.
- pgfkey or xkeyval or l3keys2e: More advanced key-value interface.
- Some packages of Oberdiek bundle: ifpdf, ifxetex, ifluatex, atbegshi, kvoptions, zref, ...
- Some packages of tools bundle: array, calc (c.f. eTeX's primitives), fontsmpl (c.f. fonttable), layout (c.f. layouts), showkeys, trace, xspace, ...
- expl3, interface3 and source3 (i.e. l3kernel bundle): Introduction of LaTeX3 syntax and documented (developing) LaTeX3 kernel.
- Some packages of l3packages bundle, especially xparse.
- Documents of pdfTeX, and maybe XeTeX and LuaTeX.

---

To be continued... I'll add links for the documents.

Comment: I made the answer CW. Any modification is welcome.

Answer (score 7):

For point 1, have a look at the following links:

[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)

[LaTeX2e for Authors](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/usrguide.pdf)

Although they refer to LaTeX2e, it should be sufficient for most applications of LaTeX.  For point number 2, have a look at the following article:

[Tools for creating LaTeX-integrated graphics and animation under GNU/Linux](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/sunol/sunol.pdf)

For point 3, have a look at the following link:

[Martin Scharrer's Website](http://www.scharrer-online.de/wiki/LaTeX/Docs/macros2e)

The document provided on this site lists the internal macros defined by the LaTeX2e base files which can also be useful to package authors.

Comment: `macros2e` is on CTAN already, you can update the link.

Comment: I must say (personally, I'm sorry), lshort is really not a good document. And it's only for beginners, but not suitable for any advance reference. A much better quick introduce to LaTeX is [ltxprimer](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf) by Indian TUG.

Comment: See the [`macros2e answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465) of mine for the updated CTAN and code repository links. I have to say that IMHO this document is not a starting point to learn how to define own macros.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks a lot. Your reference links are amazing ;)

Comment: -1 _The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e_ & linkrot: http://scharrer-online.de/