# Systematic and structured study of (Lua)(Xe)(La)TeX

Tags: documentation, tutorials

I have a general question for the TeX.SE community.

I'm a regular user of LaTeX for the last 4 years or so.

I can say with some degree of confidence that I am conversant with the bare basics of (Xe)LaTeX.

I would define an intermediate user to be able to create macros, play with the counters, tweak the page layout etc..

I would define an advanced user to be able to create class files, .sty files and packages etc..

At the entry level, I find many books and web resources. But if I have to go to the intermediate level ahead, I am afraid that there aren't much resources/books available.

I have read many comments from the members of this community that browsing the questions here can do a lot of good. I agree with that.

But I would like to see more structured and systematic presentation of the intermediate and advanced topics. Given that the software has been around for almost 3 decades, I think we should have better educational resources/material for all levels of users.

In fact, even if the questions and answers of TeX.SE are categorised and compiled into a book or web page, that would be great!

These are just my initial thoughts. I would like to invite experienced and senior members to take over.

Please edit my question/tags for clarity and relevance.

Regards.

Vrajaraja Govinda Das.

Comment: Do any of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/what-are-good-advanced-latex-books, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands answer your question? Or, starting from the basics but also covering advanced topics, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner?

Comment: @Marijn: yes, definitely. At the same time, I meant that we should start to compile them to have everything in one place.