# What does \p@ mean in some code?

Tags: macros, latex-base, octavo

I have found the source code within `octavo.dtx` (from the `octavo` package) and it has some parts called `\p@`. I have searched throughout the document but cannot understand what this is defined as or what it does and it is too short a term to do an internet search. Is this specific to the document or common to TeX? Here is a portion of the code:

```
\if@titlepage

    \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%

    \let\footnotesize\small

    \let\footnoterule\relax

    \let\footnote\thanks

%    \end{macrocode}

%    The title itself is centered vertically, with a little offset brought by

%    a |\vskip|.

%    \begin{macrocode}

    \null\vfil

    \vskip 60\p@

%    \end{macrocode}
```

- What does the `\p@` do?

Comment: This is also explained in the `macros2e` document mentioned and linked by my answer to the related [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10465/2975) question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is abbreviated notation for a `1pt` *dimension*, as included in [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) (originally in [`plain.tex`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex?view=co)) and therefore common to all LaTeX documents:

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
\newdimen\z@ \z@=0pt % can be used both for 0pt and 0
```

As such, you can use it in calculation with dimensions, such that `60\p@` translates to `60` times `1pt`, or `60pt`. In a similar fashion, `\z@` provides a `0pt` dimension.

Using

```
\makeatletter
\show\p@
\makeatother
```

yields

```
\p@=\dimen11
```

indicating that it is a TeX dimension (number 11). Consequently, issuing `\showthe\p@` yields `1.0pt` in your `.log`.

Comment: Perhaps it should be added that these shorthands are from the days when space and speed was much more limited than it is today and using them gives some tiny advantage in both dimensions. However, these days I would recomment for newly designed class files to use explicit dimensions for better readability.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Welcome to TeX.SX, Frank! What took you so long? `:)` Yes, it shows the longevity of the code.

Comment: simply the fact that my day has only 24 hours and no posting ever told me how to double it - if you know the answer to THAT then ...

Comment: What would be the effects of using `\p@=1bp` (or even something crazy like `\p@=2bp`)?

Comment: @svenper: You can search for `\p@` in [the LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) to see all the macros using it. It varies from footnotes, to certain math constructions, the ToC dotted lines, float separations from the text and other floats... it's scattered throughout, so it'll have visible affects.

Comment: This is nothing LaTeX specific. See the line 257 of plain.tex, where the original of this idea is present. But is is not so good idea for today as Frank Mittelbach mentioned.