# What is the width of the standard paragraph indent in LaTeX's article class?

Tags: indentation, article

If no changes has been made to the settings of indentation of an article class LaTeX document, what is the width of the paragraph indent?

`texdoc article` in the terminal opens the **Standard Document Classes for LaTeX version 2e** manual. In section **6.2 Paragraphing** I find the following line:

```
⟨10pt⟩ \setlength\parindent{15\p@}
```

The [`\p@`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38664/what-does-p-mean-in-some-code) means `1pt` ... so I guess this would mean that the standard indent is 15 pt at a 10 pt text size? Is this correct?

Comment: Correct you can also do `\the\parindent` to print it in a minimal or `\showthe\parindent` to see it on the terminal

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how to use the commands you wrote? I'm quite new to LaTeX.

Comment: If you insert @YiannisLazarides' macros in your document .tex file, the first will list the indent directly in your output document, while the second will list it in the log file.  Also, if you want a responding comment on this site to be brought to the attention of the person, you need to insert @ followed by the recipient name in your comment (as I have done above).  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah, I understand!

Comment: Also: if you just open a terminal and type `tex` (or `latex`), then hit return, you're given an interactive prompt where you could then type `\showthe\parindent`, hit return, and then get the output: `> 20 pt.` Then type `x` and return to exit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard classes `article` and `report` use `sizeXY.clo` to set parameters for the `XYpt` option, that is `10pt` (default), `11pt` and `12pt`.

In `size10.clo` we find

```
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\parindent{1em}
\else
  \setlength\parindent{15\p@}
\fi
```

which means that the parindent is different in `twocolumn` mode than in one column typesetting. The command `\p@` stands for a dimension register storing the value 1pt, so `15\p@` is equivalent to `15pt`. In `size11.clo` there is

```
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\parindent{1em}
\else
  \setlength\parindent{17\p@}
\fi
```

and in `size12.clo` there is

```
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\parindent{1em}
\else
  \setlength\parindent{1.5em}
\fi
```

The same values are found in `bk10.clo`, `bk11.clo` and `bk12.clo` that are used by the `book` class.

Note that these values are set after a `\normalsize` declaration, but *before* `\normalfont` is issued, so the value of `em` is the one relative to the corresponding font in the Computer Modern family.

If you want to set a value of `\parindent` in em units relative to the document font, do

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
```

(or whatever value you prefer).

Comment: Equivalently, one could use `latexdef` or `texdef` command, for example `latexdef -c '[10pt]{article}' -v parindent` will return `15.0pt`; and `latexdef -c '[11pt]{article}' -v parindent` will return  `17.0pt`.