# hanging indent with familiar footnotes in reledmac

Tags: footnotes, indentation, reledmac

I'm setting something with the reledmac package and am having trouble getting the second series of familiar footnotes to have hanging indents. I'm probably putting the command `\hangindentX` in the wrong place, but no matter where I put it, it doesn't give me what I want. This is the closest I've been able to come—it doesn't throw errors and it doesn't drop any of the text. The problem is that the indents don't match and they're normal indents rather than hanging:

[image]

An MWE is below. Any thoughts about how I can fix this?

````
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{octavo}
 
\usepackage[norule,symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[nocritical,noend,series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}

\begin{document}

Ad purpureās brācās\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{Brācæ:} Long pants.} et canāliculātās\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{Canāliculātus:} Like a channel, channeled.}\multfootsep\footnoteB[\relax]{\hangindentX{1em} \textbf{Brācæ canāliculātæ:} Channeled long pants; i.e., corduroy pants.} dēspexit, illāsque tālēs, quālibus indūta (aut indūtus) sībilum\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{sībilum:} whisper.} ēdās cum ambulēs\footnoteB[\relax]{\hangindentX{1em} \textbf{quālibus … cum ambulēs:} the kind that make a whispering sound when you walk wearing them.}

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch more poking around and experimenting, I realized that I had put `\hangindentX` in a VERY wrong place—it needs to go in the preamble, along with calling the `\reledmac` package. Once I did that, it fixed everything.

I *also* realized, for what it's worth, that I was using `\hangindentX` wrong to begin with. If I want the footnotes in series B to have hanging indents, I need to indicate that as an argument. So rather than `\hangindent{1em}`, as in the MWE I posted, I needed to have `\hangindent[B]{1em}`.

I used @Yannis Lazarides' comment on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247441/what-is-the-width-of-the-standard-paragraph-indent-in-latexs-article-class) to figure out the standard indent of the class I was using (`octavo`) and ended up with `\hangindentX[B]{10.95pt}`. Which gave me exactly what I was aiming for.

[image]

```
 
\usepackage[norule,symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[nocritical,noend,series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
**\hangindentX[B]{10.95pt}**

\begin{document}

Ad purpureās brācās\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{Brācæ:} Long pants.} et canāliculātās\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{Canāliculātus:} Like a channel, channeled.}\multfootsep\footnoteB[\relax]{\textbf{Brācæ canāliculātæ:} Channeled long pants; i.e., corduroy pants.} dēspexit, illāsque tālēs, quālibus indūta (aut indūtus) sībilum\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{sībilum:} whisper.} ēdās cum ambulēs\footnoteB[\relax]{\textbf{quālibus … cum ambulēs:} the kind that make a whispering sound when you walk wearing them. Both \emph{indūta} and \emph{indūtus} are used so as not to exclude the female reader.}

\end{document}
```