# How to get the space between chapter and text?

Tags: spacing, chapters

I am using the documentclass `book` in this example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\vspace{3cm}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```

Now I want to know the distance between the title of a chapter and the first line of the text.

[image: Output of the example above]

The space between the two lines of dummy text (b) should be the same as the space between the chapter's title and the first line (a).
There might be a default lenght which I can use instead of the 3cm which I set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\vspace{40pt}` instead of `\vspace{3cm}` should give you the desired result:

[image]

You can find this length by looking up the definition of `makeschapterhead` in the file `book.cls`. There you can find the following lines:

```
def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The important part in this case is `\vskip 40\p@`. `\p@` represents `1pt` (for an explanation see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38666/134144), so that we can use `\vspace{40pt}` in the document to get the same distance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below macro on your preamble part (i.e., before `\begin{document}`)

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
  }\vskip3cm}
  \makeatother
```