# How to trim .tex for each filename read from an external file?

Tags: programming, external-files

I have an external text file that contains a list of names of TeX input files. The names have trailing extensions `.tex`. 
For example, the external text file named `data.txt` contains the following list:

```
a.tex
b.tex
c.tex
```

There is a PDF file for each TeX input file in the same directory in which `data.txt` exists.

The following codes are expected to iterate the file name without extension and import the corresponding PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\newread\reader
\immediate\openin\reader=data.txt\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
        \includegraphics{\x}\par
\repeat
\immediate\closein\reader
\end{document}
```

Could you help me to implement the trimming macro to remove `.tex` in `\x`?

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: Throw the list into Excel and use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1;".tex";"")`. Add `.tex` whenever required by TeX.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but the `xstring` package has `\StrBefore`. Using `\StrBefore{hello.tex}{.tex}` gives me `hello`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `LaTeX2e` kernel, provides some commands for parsing paths and extensions. It is preferable to use them for this type of parsing.

The macro `\filename@parse` scans its argument and splits it into three parts which are then saved in the macros `\filename@area`, `\filename@base`, `\filename@ext`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\filename@parse{path/name.tex}
\filename@area, \filename@base, \filename@ext
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

In your case `\filename@base` will represent the trimmed filename, with no path or extension information.

Comment: Fascinating! Is there a handy reference (perhaps even a cheat-sheet) for such commands?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Yes, [`macros2e`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10465/2975).

Comment: AFAIK, this won't work correctly with `path/name.with.dots.tex`, because everything after the first, not last, dot is taken as the extension.

Comment: @MartinScharrer One shouldn't name files this way; but under normal circumstances this would work. What you interested is the _extension_ and in your example the extension is `with.dots.tex`, which you want removed. If you save a file under latex as `test.sty.tex` and you `input{test}` LaTeX will import it with no issue.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: No, `\input{test}` will try `test` and then `test.tex`, but will not find `test.sty.tex`. How should it be able to know if it is not `test.abc.tex`, `test.xyz.tex`, etc. etc.; I agree that files should not be named like that, but as say, package programmer you need to think about supporting them.

Comment: @MartinScharrer You right. However, is this a case for defensive programming? I mean has this sort of issue been an issue with `LaTeX` or `graphicx` for so many years?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: The LaTeX core mostly doesn't need to strip the extension, but uses the given name directly. This is an issue when the `.tex` extension is used with `\include`, because it is later added explicitly. With `graphicx` there are some issues, as you can see on the questions on this site about it and on the existence of the `grffile` package.

Answer (score 8):

As already stated by Yiannis Lazarides the internal LaTeX2e `\filename@parse` macro can be used to parse the file name. However, the code for splitting the extension off assumes that there is only one dot in the filename and that everything after it is the file extension. Therefore you will get incorrect results for filename with multiple dots as shown below.

I recently added support for multi-dot filenames to my `currfile` package (shows the current file name, path, extension, etc.), by reimplementing parts of the `\filename@parse` internals. Unfortunately there is no public interface, but you could use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}[2011/09/18]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\filename@parse{path/name.tex}
\filename@area, \filename@base, \filename@ext

% Will take 'width.dots.tex' as the extension
\filename@parse{path/name.with.dots.tex}
\filename@area, \filename@base, \filename@ext

% Works with internal 'currfile' redefinitions:
{
\let\filename@simple\currfile@parseext
\let\filename@base\@gobble
\filename@parse{path/name.with.dots.tex}
\filename@area, \filename@base, \filename@ext
}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible definition, in which also options for every graphic file can be stated

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newread\inclfromfile@read
\newcommand\includefromfile[2][]{%
  \openin\inclfromfile@read#2\relax
  \loop\read\inclfromfile@read to \@tempa
    \unless\ifeof\inclfromfile@read
    \filename@parse{\@tempa}%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\includegraphics[#1]{\filename@base}\noexpand\par}\x
  \repeat
  \closein\inclfromfile@read
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includefromfile[scale=1.2]{data.txt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Notice that `\immediate` does nothing before `\openin` and `\closein` (it's different from `\openout` and `\closeout`, where in the absence of `\immediate`  the commands would execute during the next `\shipout` operation that involves them).

It's important to say `\noexpand\par` as in some environments (notably `center`), `\par` is redefined as a macro.