# TeXworks and Command Line Compilation ok, But TeXShop yields different result

Tags: compiling, texworks, texshop, format-files

### Background:

As per my earlier question, [Can't get real currfile if used in precompiled .fmt file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/cant-get-real-currfile-if-used-in-precompiled-fmt-file),  I am trying to speed up compilation by generating a `.fmt` file.  The example below tests that the value of the token `\MyToken` is set to the portion of the file name between the two dashes.

I am **not** getting the desired behavior when I use `TeXShop` **and** the precompiled `.fmt` file. But, things work as expected if I use `TeXworks`, or command line compilation.  I suspect something is not quite right with the `MyLaTeX.engine` script invoked by `TeXShop`, but don't know for sure.

After saving `MyPreamble.tex` defined below, I first compile the preamble via the command line:

```
    pdflatex -ini -jobname=MyPreamble "&pdflatex MyPreamble.tex\dump"
```

Then I try to use this preamble in four different ways to process `foo-x-bar.tex`:

---

1. Command Line compilation (*works*):

   ```
   pdflatex  --file-line-error --shell-escape -fmt=MyPreamble -recorder --synctex=1                   foo-x-bar.tex
   ```

   yields the correct result (no red error message):

   [image]

   Furthermore, the following (change how the file name is specified, see the "Update" section below) also works:

   ```
   pdflatex  --file-line-error --shell-escape -fmt=MyPreamble -recorder --synctex=1                    ./foo-x-bar.tex
   ```
2. Using TeXworks (*works*):

   With `MyLaTeX` configured as

   [image]

   I get identical results as command line compilation (again, no red error message).
3. Using `TeXShop` (**does not** work):

   With TeXShop things are *not* quite the same. I have the following file saved as `MyLaTeX.engine`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
   pdflatex --file-line-error --shell-escape -fmt=MyPreamble -recorder --synctex=1 "$bfname"
   ```

   and invoking `MyLaTeX` from `TeXShop`, I get the dreaded red error message:

   [image]
4. Compiling the `foo-x-barComplete.tex`, which is simply:

   ```
   \input{MyPreamble.tex}
   \input{foo-x-bar.tex}
   ```

   directly via `LaTeX` on `TeXShop`, and `pfdlatex` on `TeXworks`, things also work fine (no red error message).

---

So, the problem *only* occurs on `TeXShop` **with** the precompiled `.fmt` file.

---

### Update:

- After posting the question, I do see one difference in the `TeXShop` run in that the file name is prefixed with `./`.   And I am extracting the text between the first and second dash with:

  ```
  \StrBefore{\themainfile}{.}[\CurrentFileName]%
  \StrBetween[1,2]{\CurrentFileName}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]
  ```

  This seemed to be the problem (since there are now two dots in the file name). So, I attempted the obvious fix which is to extract the file name *before* `.tex`:

  ```
  \StrBefore{\themainfile}{.tex}[\CurrentFileName]%
  ```

  Now I get identical results with both `TeXShop`  and `TeXworks`, **but** now both show the dreaded error messages!!!

  Ok, so the fix lies in this code, or the `.engine` file.

  However it should be noted that the command line invocation with a leading `./` before the file name does not have a problem.

### Temporary Solution:

Found a temporary solution:

```
    \StrBetween[1,2]{\themainfile}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]%
```

but I would prefer to find a method that extracts this from the file name with the extension removed, which is what the above code attempts to do.

---

### Code: `MyPreamble.tex`:

```
% Based on egreg's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/cant-get-real-currfile-if-used-in-precompiled-fmt-file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}% 

\newcommand*{\Debug}[1]{\par\noindent\textcolor{blue}{#1}\par}%
\newcommand*{\Error}[1]{\par\noindent\textcolor{red}{#1}\par}%

\newtoks{\MyToken}
\MyToken={oo}% set default value
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \getmainfile
    \Debug{Debug: themainfile = "\themainfile"}%
    \StrBefore{\themainfile}{.}[\CurrentFileName]% 
    \Debug{Debug: CurrentFileName = "\CurrentFileName"}%
    \StrBetween[1,2]{\CurrentFileName}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]%
    \Debug{Debug: ExtractedValue = "\ExtractedValue"}%
    %
    %\StrBetween[1,2]{\jobname}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]% this works
    \IfStrEq*{\ExtractedValue}{\the\MyToken}{}{%
        \Error{Error: MyToken (middle) was "\the\MyToken",
                but was expected to be "\ExtractedValue".}%
    }%
}
%% ----- preamble ends here
```

---

### Code: `foo-x-bar.tex`:

```
% This file need to be named in three parts separated by two dashes.
% This need to be set to be the value in between the two dashes. So,
% if this file is named "foo-x-bar.tex", then this needs to be "x"
\MyToken={x}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Code:

Comment: File name manipulation is always tricky! Remember that `./../Folder/./././../././Folder/file.tex` is a valid name of a file in the current folder, as long as it's name is `Folder` ;)

Comment: @tohecz: Well, yeah, but that is why I thought getting the string _before_ `.tex` instead of before the `.` should have worked.  I am not looking for a general solution that will cover all wacky cases of file names. So, I am thinking that if perhaps the `bash` script would pass the file name to `pfdlatex` without the leading `./` then it _might_ just work...

Comment: *You* are adding the `./` with ``bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"`` Try with ``bfname=$(basename "$1".tex)`` or, better yet, ``bfname="$1"`` (I don't see why extracting what's before the extension and adding the extension again).

Comment: @egreg: That certainly does the job with `TeXShop`, but only if I use `\StrBefore{\themainfile}{.}[\CurrentFileName]`, which is what I was originally doing since there was only one `.` to deal with, and your suggestion here does. So, this seems like an answer.  As an aside, why does it fail with if I instead use `\StrBefore{\themainfile}{.tex}[\CurrentFileName]`.

Comment: @egreg: You should add that as answer so we can mark this as being answered.

Comment: This might also be helpful: [How to trim .tex for each filename read from an external file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39636)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the file is in the same directory, which is the case here,

```
$(dirname "$1")
```

returns `.`; so

```
bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
```

when the file is `foo-x-bar.tex` stores

./foo-x-bar.tex

as the value of `bfname`. Just use

```
bfname="$1"
```

(or use directly `$1`, of course). Indeed with

```
bfname="`basename "$1" .tex`"
```

you'd be removing the extension just to reinsert it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It is a quite old post but a more general and most simple answer is worth providing it here.

*I never used TeXShop (no Mac at hand) but what follows works well  in TeXworks and TeXmaker on both Windows and Linux, and also from older versions of Winedt.*

The solution is twofold :

1. Fist of all, keep in mind that the TeX "old fashion" to provide a non-standard format is based on the `&` (ampersand) key.  This can be used on the command line, or as the very first line of the latex file e.g as :
    `%&"myCustonFormat"`
   Notice the `%` which followed by `&` acts as a magic comment which is  passed to (la)tex, exactly as it would be done from the command line.
2. Secondly, the creation of the custom format is mostly simplified by the [`mylatexformat.ltx` TeX program](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat) 
   This program does the whole job needed to create the format with the command line:

   ```
   pdflateX -initialize -jobname="myCustonFormat" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "mySourceFile.tex"
   ```

I am used to work with a per-project-custom-format named as the main file and use:

```
pdflateX -initialize -jobname="myFile" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "myFile.tex"
```

This command can be configured as typesetting tool in TeXworks as shown on this picture:

[image: TeXworks config MakeCustom ormat]

Finally a MWE is :

```
%&"mwe"
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\csname endofdump\endcsname
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\subsection{subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
\end{document}
```

In this code I included the heavy `pgf/tikz` package  in the preamble, to be incorporated in the custom format, while the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`, being placed after the `\csname endofdump\endcsname`, is *not* included in the format, and can therefore be modified without to need to rebuild the custom format. The second line is a TeWworks-style magic command interpreted by the editor only, in contrast to the first one which is interpreted by the (pdf)(la)tex compiler.

Of course the format created here by using the above shown typesetting tools will be called `mwe.fmt`, but can be renamed. If oen intend to create a sytem- or user-wide custom format, it is worth using one time the command line, thus providing a more meaningful `jobname`to be used to name the format.

Comment: As diplayed in OP, le initex option in TeXLive is `-ini` while it is `-initialize` in MiKTeX.
I also observed that when the custom format is declared on the very first line or the source file, it should be quoted in MiKteX and not quoted in TeXLive (tested on TL 2015 and 2013 on Linux).