# \show with fewer lines?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I am writing some macros for general debugging purposes (See [Yiannis' question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/introspection-and-reflection-with-latex-tex-macros)). I am basically expanding a given input step by step, and printing the result to the terminal and log. In order for this to happen step by step, I am using `\show`, which interrupts TeX and gives the user the opportunity to follow what is going on.

However, `\show` is quite verbose: at least six lines, most of which are useless. Can this number be reduced? (I don't mind dropping `\show` for a better alternative.)

Namely,

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\errorcontextlines=-1\relax % attempt to have less lines
\def\deeper{\show\deepest...}
\def\deep{A \deeper macro}
\deep
\end{document}
```

writes the following to the terminal:

```
> \deepest=undefined.
\deeper ->\show \deepest 
                         ...
l.6     \deep

?
```

Comment: Is stopping the TeX run a key part of the question here, of is the main concern writing to the log? (For example would it be acceptable to write several lines to the log and only interrupt the run once?)

Comment: @Joseph: the best would be to stop TeX, but not write anything else than the prompt "?" to the terminal. I don't care much about the log: it can be post-processed later if we need to extract information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define your own `\show` using `\message` and `\meaning`.
You can stop the compilation by reading some dummy input:

```
\def\myshow#1{%
    \message{\string#1=\meaning#1^^J?}%
    {\read-1 to \dummy}%
}
```

Example:

```
\def\example{Example macro}
\myshow\example
```

Results in:

```
\example=macro:->Example macro
?
```

See [*The TeXBook*](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html) in Chapter 20: "Definitions (also called Macros)" on page 217 for more details.

Comment: thanks, `\read0 to` is exactly what I needed! (I already take care of finding the meaning etc., and outputting it using the hardwrap package) And `\read` also allows to take user input in a much cleaner way than `\show` (e.g., no need for `I` at the start).

Comment: Please note that I edited to `\read-1` to suppress the prompt. I just had to look `\read` up in the TeXBook again to check how to do it.