# How do I use \show?

Tags: macros

Q: How do I use `\show` to determine macro definitions?.

I've followed advice here: [The definitions of LaTeX commands](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds) and here: [\show with fewer lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10053/show-with-fewer-lines) and am still struggling.

I've naively tried running `\show\section` (to learn about the macro `\section`) in the WinEdt terminal. No luck. I've placed this code in a simple `.tex` document to be compiled. No luck.

Note: this is a follow-up to my question: [LaTeX equivalent to R's `help foo`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/latex-equivalent-to-rs-help-foo)

Comment: welcome and I wish you the best in finding what you need.  When formatting questions it's best if you provide the target link's document title as the link's text, as I did in my edits.

Comment: @Matthew: Got it. Just used your advice in a new post. Thx.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I find `\show` is most useful when used interactively:

```
b@poppy:~$ latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.

*\documentclass{article}

*\show\section

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> \section=\long macro:
->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@p
lus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }.
<*> \show\section

? x
No pages of output.
```

Note the trick in getting LaTeX to talk to you: tell it to `\relax`.

Comment: Interesting, I've never had much use for interactive mode, but this is a good idea.

Comment: I too do this a lot. In fact, any control sequence suffices to get TeX to start paying attention to you. I frequently start with `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: really cool. I'll be using that. Thx!

Comment: @TH, thanks for the info- I did not know that.  I thought it was expecting a file name and \relax told it that it wasn't getting one.

Answer (score 17):

The output is shown on the terminal and in the log file. for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\section
```

prints

```
> \section=\long macro:
->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@p
lus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }.
l.2 \show\section
```

and now TeX is asking what you want to do. If you enter `X`, it will exit.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for the help. Yes, I think things were working before then. I just wasn't distinguishing this output from the rest. I'm curious which commands I can supply other than `X`. e.g., is there a command that will ignore the `\show\section` and produce a `.pdf`? I've posted this as follow-up question at [commands in interaction mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/commands-in-interaction-mode)

Comment: @brianjd: You can type `?` to get TeX to tell you what else it responds to. That being S, R, Q, I, 1, 2, ..., 9, H, or X. See the help for what those do. I never use S, R, or Q, but the others are useful.