# commands in interaction mode?

Tags: tex-core, macros

Q: Which commands can I supply back to LaTeX when it pauses on a line of code during compilation and is waiting for me to give it more information before proceeding?

E.g., in the post [How do I use \show?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11907/how-do-i-use-show) (to which this question is a follow-up) I found that with `\show\section` in my code the LaTeX compilation would pause and I would get useful information about `\section` printed to the terminal. I could supply `X` back to the terminal and have the program exit (printing that useful information already mentioned to a .log file).

Q: So, what **other** commands could I supply at this point?

I'm having trouble finding information on the web regarding this. The post [Different LaTeX interaction modes](http://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2007-October/032384.html) mentions that `q` will get LaTeX to proceed in a different, "quiet" mode. Running this, I see that something different is happening in the log-file. However (as with `X`) no `.pdf` is created.

Q: Is there a command I can supply that would sort of ignore the `\show\section` command in my `.tex` file and produce a `.pdf`?

Comment: a tip: It's best if you don't post answers in your question. (It's a _question_, after all!) However, if you have things to tell that are not contained in the answer you just got, it's quite OK if you post an _answer_ to your own question. (I'd recommend removing everything from the question that looks like an answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, what other commands could I supply at this point?

At the prompt you can enter a question mark to see the possible commands:

```
/tmp $ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2010)
**\show\x
> \x=undefined.
<*> \show\x

? ?
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, 
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
?
```

> Is there a command I can supply that would sort of ignore the `\show\section` command in my .tex file and produce a .pdf?

Press return, then the compilation proceeds. However, `\show` is always treated as an error:

```
/tmp $ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2010)
**\show\x
> \x=undefined.
<*> \show\x

? 

*\null

*\bye
[1]
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 196 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
/tmp $ echo $?
1
```

So you should use `\show` only for debugging purposes, not for normal compilation runs. If you want to print the meaning of a control sequence without giving an error, use `\immediate\write16{\meaning\foo}` (in LaTeX, `\typeout` is equivalent to `\immediate\write16`).

Comment: @Phillip. Wonderful. Tested it out and everything works perfectly (i.e., `\typeout` and `?`). Thx!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE AND PARTIAL ANSWER: by running latex in interaction mode (typing `latex` in the command window directly) and proceeding along I'm given a message that basically says:

`<return>` to proceed
`S` to scroll future error messages
`R` to run without stopping
`Q` to run quietly
`H` for help
`X` to quit

I found that actually entering `R` doesn't lead to a `.pdf` being produced as I'd hoped. I'm starting to think that including `\show\section` in my code will prevent that from happening no matter which command I supply.

ANOTHER UPDATE: See @Phillipp for the answer. `\show\section` will always be processed as an error and will not allow production of a `.pdf`. Should be run as a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Going back to where we started,

```
\def\myshow#1{\typeout{\string#1: \meaning#1}%
  \read 0 to \carryon
}
```

does the `\show` part of what you were after, and then prompts you to carry
on (ignoring what you write, merely paying attention to the fact that you
wrote *something*).

[It comes from a post somewhere, recently; my test harness has long
had the `\typeout` bit, but not the `\read` bit.]

(I had never noticed that responses to those "press ... to proceed" things affected the return code from the TeX command and/or production of real
output.  unobservant sort of guy, y'see...)

Comment: a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.