# Print macro output instead of executing

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, debugging

I am attempting to debug a Tikz/PGF script. I have a STY file that generates Tikz/PGF scripts, but the output graphic isn't quite what I want it to be.

In order to debug the problem, I was hoping that I could tweak my code so that the Tikz/PGF script is printed to the LaTeX document (in a verbatim environment, for example) instead of being executed by tikzpicture.

Here is a small example of what I am after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\theCommand[1]{%
\node [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em] {#1};%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \theCommand{test}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code would draw a rectangular box with the text "test" inside. However, ideally I instead want this to print out the text:

```
\node [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em] {test};
```

Comment: Using verbatim is an option?

Comment: @azetina Yes, but just changing tikzpicture to verbatim doesn't have the desired effect as it will print "\theCommand{test}" instead

Comment: Outside the `tikzpicture` environment, issuing `{\ttfamily\meaning\theCommand}` gives the meaning of `\theCommand` (without passing arguments to it). See, for example, [Equivalent of `\show` to display the LaTeX code in the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20365/5764) and [The definitions of LaTeX commands](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ltxcmds).

Comment: @JoshuaSpence Do you want the output of `\tracingall`? If so, you are looking at a _lot_ of code for any realistic TikZ picture!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how useful this is for you, but here are two options.  Perhaps you can adapt one for your particular case:

### 1. `showexpl` Package:

I would recommend you use [the `showexpl` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl), which will typeset the content and also list the LaTeX code:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\lstdefinestyle{myLatexStyle}{
    language=TeX,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={align,begin},
    pos=l
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLatexStyle, pos=b]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, 
         rounded corners, minimum height=4em] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

---

### 2. Replace `\node` macro:

The above solution will only show the code that is within the `LTXexample` environment.  So if you still wanted to use a separate drawing macro, the above would only show `\theCommand{test};` in the output, which does not provide much information.  An alternative is if you replace:

```
\newcommand\theCommand[1]{%
    \node [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, 
           rounded corners, minimum height=4em] {#1};%
}
```

to use `\ShowAndExecuteNode` instead of `\node`:

```
\newcommand\theCommand[1]{%
    \ShowAndExecuteNode[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, 
           rounded corners, minimum height=4em]{#1}%
}
```

then you get the output:

[image]

Commenting out the `\AtEndDocument{\TikzCodeList}` will eliminate this output.

### Notes:

- This adapts Herbert's solution from [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time) to print the macro's options at the end of the document.
- Not sure how useful this is as it depends on how the rest of the picture is drawn.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\TikzCodeList{}%
\newcommand\AddTikzCode[1]{\xdef\TikzCodeList{\TikzCodeList#1\endgraf}}%
\AtEndDocument{\TikzCodeList}%

\newcommand{\ShowAndExecuteNode}[2][]{%
    \node [#1] {#2};
    \AddTikzCode{node [#1] #2}%
}%

\newcommand\theCommand[1]{%
    \ShowAndExecuteNode[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \theCommand{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```