# How reuse latex code for later expansion?

Tags: macros

I would like to make a command to help me writing lines like:

```
The \LaTeX~code is: \verb@e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0@, and the result is: $e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0$.
```

I thought of using a newcommand as:

```
\newcommand{\eqn}[1]{The \LaTeX~code is: \verb@#1@, and the result is: $#1$.}
```

to use as:

```
\eqn{e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0}
```

which doesn't work.

Trying to pull out the verbatim out as:

```
\newcommand{\eqn1}[1]{The \LaTeX~code is: #1, and the result is: $#1$.}
```

to use as:

```
\eqn1{\verb@e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0@}
```

also doesn't work.

My question is, is there a way to achieve this in latex?

Thank you.
PS: unfortunately the thread bellow seems to indicate that it's not possible :(
[Wrapping code (listings, verbatim, or other method) inside a newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand)

Comment: Regarding the second definition, there are two things which would cause errors: LaTeX commands cannot contain numbers (so `\eqn1` generates a `Missing \begin{document}` error); and your `eqn1` command takes math and pastes it into the document inside textmode, so you'll get a bunch of errors from that (e.g. `^` is not allowed in textmode).

Comment: Also related: [How to put `\verb` command inside of `\textbf` block?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/5764)

Answer (score 6):

Absorb the argument verbatim and rescan it when you need the real output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqn}{v}
 {
  The~\LaTeX{}~code~is:~\texttt{#1},~and~the~
  result~is:~\tl_rescan:nn { } { $#1$ }.
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\eqn{e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I really need to look more into `expl3` programming.

Answer (score 2):

With inspiration from [this answer by Ulrich Schwarz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20366/15830), we can solve this using `\meaning`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\meaningbody[1]{%
  {\ttfamily
    \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}%
}
\newcommand\eqn[1]{%
  {\def\@foo{$#1$}The \LaTeX~code is \meaningbody\@foo, and the result is: $#1$.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\eqn{e^{i\pi} - 1 = 0}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

One potential problem is that the output from `\meaning` is not exactly the same as the input code. There is an extra space after `\pi` in this example.

Comment: (This is just detokenize in e-TeX.)