# Display source for a command

Tags: macros

When using `renewcommand`, sometimes I wish to first check what the original source code for a particular command, such as `chapter` was before I change it, so that I can be certain that I do not make unintended changes. When I have a lot of packages loaded, sometimes looking through the source code of a package to find the answer is not so simple. Is there a way to print out the source code used to define a particular command?

Comment: `\show` and `\meaning`. See [how do i use show](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11907/how-do-i-use-show) and [equivalent of show to display the latex code in the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20365/equivalent-of-show-to-display-the-latex-code-in-the-document)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/introspection-and-reflection-with-latex-tex-macros

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined

Answer (score 62, accepted):

- Use `\meaning`, `\show` to get the meaning of a macro. (See TeXbook or TeX by Topic)
- Use `\the`, `\showthe` to get the value of registers. (See TeXbook or TeX by Topic)
- Use `\tracingcommands`, `\tracingmacros` (See TeXbook or TeX by Topic) and `trace` package to get more information in the log file.
- Use eTeX's `\ifdefined`, `\ifcsname` (See eTeX's manual) or LaTeX command `\@ifundefined` (See `source2e`) or `\ifx\foo\undefined` trick to check whether a macro is defined.
- Use LaTeX command `\CheckCommand` (described in `clsguide`) to check the definition of a LaTeX macro.

Comment: `\show\big` failed for me (TeXLive 2018 on macOS). The solution based on `texdef` worked, however (see below).

Comment: How do I find out what package a command is from?

Answer (score 28):

Yes, using `\show\mycommand` will print the macro definition of `\mycommand` to the console (your `.log` file).

For example, compiling

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
test
\show\chapter
\end{document}
```

outputs

```
> \chapter=\long macro:
->\if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi \thispagestyle {plain}\gl
obal \@topnum \z@ \@afterindentfalse \secdef \@chapter \@schapter .
```

to the console. Note that the alignment of the output is not the same as when it is typed in code. As such, it is sometimes easier seeing the exact structure (if properly indented) when viewing the source directly. Here is the source entry from [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) for `\chapter`:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Also note that using `\show` only shows one level of expansion for the given macro. Using the above as example, one would have to issue (say) `\show\@chapter` and `\show\@schapter` (with the appropriate category code modification via `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` pairs) to see the meaning of subsequent calls within `\chapter`.

`\meaning` can be used in a similar context.

---

From the [TeX Book](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) (p 10):

> You can display the meaning of a control sequence while running TeX.
>   If you type `\show\cs` where `\cs` is any control sequence, TeX will
>   respond with its current meaning. For example, `\show\input` results
>   in `> \input=\input.`, because `\input` is primitive. On the other
>   hand, `\show\thinspace` yields
>
> ```
> > \thinspace=macro:
> ->\kern .16667em .
> ```
>
> This means that `\thinspace` has been defined as an abbreviation for
>   `\kern .16667em`. By typing `\show\kern` you can verify that `\kern`
>   is primitive. The results of `\show` appear on your terminal and in
>   the `.log` file that you get after running TeX.

Comment: Addon: Note: If `\show\foo` only results in `\protect\foo` it's a protected command. You may either show the definition of that by `\expandafter\show\csname foo \endcsname` or the tricky `{\let\protect\show\foo}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/cunning-latex-tricks).

Comment: This is awesome. I had no idea you could do this!

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`texdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdef) to print definitions in a terminal. To use it with LaTeX definitions you have to either call it with the option `-t latex` or use the corresponding alias `latexdef` (if the alias is defined on your system).

To check the definition for `\chapter` you can issue `texdef -t latex -c book chapter`. The reason that you have to invoke it with the option `-c book` is that the `\chapter` you seem to be looking for is defined in that class. To also check in which file the definition is to be found add the option `-f` or `-F` for the full path. On my system `texdef -t latex -c book -F chapter` returns

```
\chapter first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls".

\chapter:
\long macro:->\if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi \thispagestyle {plain}\global \@topnum \z@ \@afterindentfalse \secdef \@chapter \@schapter
```

If you want to see the available options for `texdef` or learn more about it you can access its documentation with `texdoc texdef`.

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me for `\big` and `\bigl`, for example.