# code defining colors in LaTeX

Tags: color

I am looking for the TeX source code for the `\color` function call in the [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en) library which I am importing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}    

{ \color{blue!60!white} abc }    

\end{document}
```

I am asking here rather than on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) because I am asking for the programming rather than just the tex commands.  In theory, this is working TeX code and I should just move on.

Comment: You have a strange idea about what is on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, if you're just interested in what `\color` does, then you can issue

```
{\let\protect\show\color}
```

in your document and check your `.log`:

```
> \color =\long macro:
->\@ifnextchar [\@undeclaredcolor \@declaredcolor .
```

This works because `\color` is declared to be [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764), otherwise [issuing `\show\color`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36955/5764) would have worked.

The code shows that `\color` conditions on whether or not the input stream contains `[`. That is,

```
\color[<options>]{<colour>}
```

would lead to executing `\@undeclaredcolor`, while calling

```
\color{<colour>}
```

would lead to executing `\@declaredcolor`. In both cases, the `{<colour>}` argument is gobbled by either `\@undeclaredcolor` or `\@declaredcolor`.

---

If you wish to follow a more detailed path of macro execution and expansion, issuing the [tracing command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764)

```
{\tracingmacros1
\color{blue!60!white} abc }
```

would allow you to debug quite a bit, revealing [a lengthy macro expansion pattern of about 800 lines](http://pastebin.com/dQKGW0KN) as one follows deeper down the rabbit hole, starting, of course, with the `\@ifnextchar` condition mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

```
\long\def\color@b@x#1#2#3%
 {\leavevmode
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\kern\fboxsep{\set@color#3}\kern\fboxsep}%
  \dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\ht\z@\dimen@
  \dimen@\dp\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\dp\z@\dimen@
  {#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}}
```

Not much to look at.  Argument `#3` seems to be the color.  The last line looks most important.

```
{#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}
```

[Why do LaTeX internal commands have an @ in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them)

Comment: Isn't this for a colour box rather than just a colour switch?