# How can I see definition of an existing math symbol?

Tags: symbols, metafont

I want to create a symbol similar to `\doublebarwedge` from the package `mathabx`, with the wedge replaced by a triangle. Since I want to use both symbols, they should be as similar as possible (regarding size, height, spacing etc.). This is why I would like to see how the symbol `\doublebarwedge` is defined. I couldn't find anything in the package documentation.

This is not a duplicate: see the comment by David Charlisle below.

Comment: it's like asking how to see the definition of "g" it is not something defined in tex it is something constructed by the font designer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display source for a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/display-source-for-a-command)

Comment: @AlexRecuenco It's not really a duplicate, you would find out there that it's `\doublebarwedge=\mathchar"255A` but that doesn't answer the question here of how to see how big the wedge is to make a matching triangle

Comment: @David, seeing his response to jknappen wonderful answer, I think that is what Larry was looking for. Since, after seeing that it was a font character, he understood that it was out of his reach. Which he would have seen immediately if he had simply typed `\show\doublebarwedge`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mathabx fonts are distributed with METAFONT source code. The relevant source for the double bar wedge sign is found in the file `mathabx/source/mathltkl.mf` and reads:

```
beginchar(wedge_eqq,12u#+2appr#,asc_height#,0);% strange choice
  "Wedge-equal sign";
  pickup tiny.nib;
  top y2r=x_height; bot y1r=0; y1r=y1l=y3r=y3l;
  x2r=good.x 0.5w;
  x3r-x2r=x2r-x1r=hround((y2r-y1r+o)/sqrt3);% see wedge sign (+o)
  x1l-x1r=diag_width(rth-tiny,z2r-z1r);
  x3r-x3l=diag_width(rth-tiny,z2r-z3r);
  z2l-z1l=whatever*(z2r-z1r); z2l-z3l=whatever*(z2r-z3r);
  pos4(rth,90); pos5(rth,90); pos6(rth,90); pos7(rth,90);
  y4r=y5r=y2r; y6=y7=y4+spread1;
  lft x4=min(Appr,lft x1r); x5-x3r=x1r-x4; x4=x6; x5=x7;
  filldraw stroke z1e--z2e--z3e; filldraw stroke z4e..z5e;
  filldraw stroke z6e..z7e; penlabels(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
endchar;
```

For creating a matching triangle, you just need to change the first `filldraw stroke` instruction to

```
   filldraw stroke z1e--z2e--z3e--z1e; % Close the drawing path
```

Of course you need to build a METAFONT infrastructure around the final source code with driver files and macro packages ( It is easy to grasp from the structure of the mathabx package; There are "driver files" like `matha10.mf`, macro files like `mathbase.mf` and finally the character sources like `mathsymb.mf`. Rename all changed files and plug it together. Feel free to ask another question on this site, when you don't get it right on your own).

Comment: This looks more complicated than I had expected (I was expecting something like `\overset{=}{\wedge}`with some spacing-adjustments added). Since I don't know how to deal with driver files etc. I'll probably just stick to defining both symbols myself. But thanks anyway for the detailed answer!