# Is there any difference between \gets and \leftarrow

Tags: arrows

Similarly, is there any difference between `\rightarrow` and `\to`?
From what I could see, they are just aliases.

Comment: Indeed they are the same

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`fontmath.ltx` (generated by `fontdef.dtx`) defines

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"20}
  \let\gets=\leftarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"21}
  \let\to=\rightarrow
```

so they print exactly the same *glyph* in the LaTeX format.

**EDIT** As clemens points out, there is a semantic difference. I use `\to` and `\gets` when dealing with functions, like in

```
$f\colon A \to B$
```

On the other hand, if I had to define some symbol containing an arrow to the right, I would never use `\to` but rather `\rightarrow`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that the difference is semantics: one name describes the symbol the other the function

Comment: Yes. You can also see that with the `\show`command. See <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11907/how-do-i-use-show>

Comment: @clemens Good point, thanks. Feel free to edit if you've got a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Just to give some context: the purpose is to write a script that would convert `\to`/`\gets`/`\leftarrow`/`\writearrow` into the appropriate Unicode characater

Comment: I wish `\to` and `\gets` were documented in the LaTeX manual. I started using plain TeX and then AMSTeX, where the commands are documented. The first versions of LaTeX loaded a slightly modified `plain.tex` file, so it was quite easy to port plain TeX files. In particular it kept `\to` and `\gets`, which never found their way in the manual.

Comment: The term "plain LaTeX format" is a bit confusing, as there is the "Plain TeX format". (The latter is described in great detail in the TeXbook.) Better to omit the modifier "plain" when referring to LaTeX. Thus, do write "in the basic LaTeX format" or, if you want to be more specific, "in the file `fontmath.ltx`" -- as you have, in fact, done already in your answer.

Comment: @Mico Thanks; fixed that. It _did_ sound a wee bit strange: what I meant is that I'm not sure whether some package may mess with that.