# A LaTeX log analyzer application (visualizing TeX expansion)

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, debugging, logging

> This question led to a new package:
>   [**`unravel`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unravel)

Consider the following MWE, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\tracingassigns=1
\tracingmacros=1

\def\aaa{something}
\def\bbb{else \aaa, else}
\edef\ccc{third \bbb, level}

\tracingassigns=0
\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

If you build this with `pdflatex test.tex` - then in the logfile, `test.log`, you get something like this (<sub>*linebreaks added for legibility*</sub>):

```
{into \tracingassigns=1}
{changing \tracingmacros=0}
{into \tracingmacros=1}


{changing \aaa=undefined}
{into \aaa=macro:->something}

{changing \bbb=undefined}
{into \bbb=macro:->else \aaa , else}

\bbb ->else \aaa , else

\aaa ->something

{changing \ccc=undefined}
{into \ccc=macro:->third else something, else, le\ETC.}


{changing \tracingassigns=1}
```

Now, this explains the expansion steps done by (La)Tex quite well for this short example - unfortunately, it becomes extremely hard to read (for me) once you have to deal with possibly hundreds of these expansions, some maybe dealing with typesetting procedures.

So I was thinking - it shouldn't be too extremely difficult to build an application, which would basically read the logfile line by line, and allow for "stepping" through the logfile; I'd imagine rightarrow keyboard key <kbd>-></kbd> would step you forward through the log, and leftarrow key <kbd><-</kbd> would step backwards; possibly, one could specify line number of the logfile as a starting point as well.

Then, the application would simply react on '`^{changing`', '`^{into`', and possibly '`^\\(.*)->(.*)`'; and would display the line, as well as the "current" token elsewhere on screen; so at the "changing" line, the extra portion of the screen would say `\aaa=undefined`; and upon "into" line, the snippet would change to `\aaa=macro:->something`.

I think just this facility would make visualizing and understanding the (La)Tex expansion process much more easy (especially in "real" documents). And in fact, such an application doesn't even need a full-blown GUI - I'd imagine a `ncurses` terminal application would do just as well (problems with display of long strings in limited width terminal notwithstanding).

So, I was wondering - is there any application similar to this out there?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing like this exists yet.  Keeping track of definitions and other unexpandable commands is straightforward, as you describe.  However, expansion can become nested very deeply.  Consider for instance `\def\a#1;{8#18}\expandafter\a\number\a2;;`  At first, a simple macro definition, then `{\expandafter}`, `{\number}`, `\a #1;->8#18`, `#1<-2`, `\a #1;->8#18`, `#1<-828`...  Very hard to keep track of which `\a` is being expanded when.  I suspect that the correct approach would be to modify the engine itself, but I still don't know how the expansion would be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, @BrunoLeFloch - I completely overlooked such cases when I was typing the question; now I can see better that even "just" reading the logfiles would not necessarily be straightforward.. Cheers!

Comment: An answer I wrote to a question from Yiannis, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9340/2707 may be of interest for what you're trying to achieve.  I tried several times to have a general solution, but it is very hard.

Comment: I have not tried it my self, but I think TeXStudio could help you. It has a built in log analizer.

Comment: Note that I'm working on a LaTeX package which could provide an aswer to this question. See [the discussion in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8058693#8058693). It's not strictly an interactive application, but you get a lot of "interaction value" by lots of navigation links in the pretty-printed log file.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Any progress? You might answer the question with a provisional report.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, not since I wrote the comment. I think I can come back to it soon now. As the OP explicitly asked for macro expansion I believe it doesn't warrant an answer yet.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

EDIT: This answer led to (in fact, is) a package: the [`unravel` package](https://github.com/blefloch/latex-unravel), on GitHub.  It relies on the [`gtl` package](https://github.com/blefloch/latex-gtl), so if you want to help me by testing, you'll need to grab this as well.  Both packages are written using the LaTeX3 programming language provided by the `expl3` package (`l3kernel`) and some extensions in `l3experimental`.

I have now implemented most of TeX's primitives.  The parts missing are math mode, tables (`\halign` etc.), discretionaries (including `\-`), the output routine, `\aftergroup`, `\letterspacefont`, `\pdfcopyfont`, `\pdfprimitive`, and all XeTeX and LuaTeX goodies.  Unavoidably also, category codes are fixed when files are opened the first time, `\outer` macros will break the package, and begin-group and end-group characters other than left and right braces will cause trouble.  Despite all those restrictions, `\unravel{\documentclass{article}\relax}` will show you all the nitty gritty details of what TeX does when going through `article.cls` (and before this, all the work that comes into deciding whether or not a file is worth reading).  Beware: at full speed, this takes several minutes and 20000 steps.

As of now, the `unravel` package only provides a very simple interface to monitor TeX's activities while it is going through the expansion and typesetting process.  One can only go forward.  Let us give an example of use.  Put the following code in a file, say `filename.tex`, and run `pdflatex filename.tex` in a terminal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unravel}
\AtEndDocument{\message{Bye!}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

After a small welcome message, `\unravel` will wait for your input.  Either go through steps one at a time, by pressing the key `enter`, or type `s20o1` ("*s*croll 20 steps but still *o*utput") then `enter`.  In the latter case, the output is (similar to, depending on the version) what follows.

```
======== Welcome to the unravel package ========
"<|" denotes the output to TeX's stomach.
"||" denotes tokens waiting to be used.
"|>" denotes tokens that we will act on.
Press <enter> to continue; 'h' <enter> for help.

|> \AtEndDocument {\message {Bye!}}
s20o1
[===== Step 1 =====] 
\AtEndDocument = macro:->\g@addto@macro \@enddocumenthook .
|> \g@addto@macro \@enddocumenthook {\message {Bye!}}
[===== Step 2 =====] 
\g@addto@macro = \long macro:#1#2->\begingroup \toks@ \expandafter {#1#2}\xdef
#1{\the \toks@ }\endgroup .
|> \begingroup \toks@ \expandafter {\@enddocumenthook \message {Bye!}}\xdef
|> \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 3 =====] \begingroup = \begingroup.
<| \begingroup 
|> \toks@ \expandafter {\@enddocumenthook \message {Bye!}}\xdef
|> \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 4 =====] \toks@ = \toks0.
<| \begingroup 
|| \toks@ 
|> \expandafter {\@enddocumenthook \message {Bye!}}\xdef \@enddocumenthook
|> {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 5 =====] \expandafter {.
<| \begingroup 
|| \toks@ \expandafter {
|> \@enddocumenthook \message {Bye!}}\xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@
|> }\endgroup 
[===== Step 6 =====] \@enddocumenthook = macro:->.
<| \begingroup 
|| \toks@ \expandafter {
|> \message {Bye!}}\xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 7 =====] back_input: \expandafter {.
<| \begingroup 
|| \toks@ 
|> {\message {Bye!}}\xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 8 =====] Set \toks@(\toks0)=\message {Bye!}.
<| \begingroup 
|> \xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 9 =====] \xdef .
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef 
|> \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 10 =====] \@enddocumenthook .
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook 
|> {\the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 11 =====] {.
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook {
|> \the \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 12 =====] \the .
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the 
|> \toks@ }\endgroup 
[===== Step 13 =====] \toks@ .
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook {\the \toks@ 
|> }\endgroup 
[===== Step 14 =====] \message {Bye!}.
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook {\message {Bye!}
|> }\endgroup 
[===== Step 15 =====] }.
<| \begingroup 
|| \xdef \@enddocumenthook {\message {Bye!}}
|> \endgroup 
[===== Step 16 =====] Set \@enddocumenthook=macro:->\message {Bye!}.
<| \begingroup 
|> \endgroup 
[===== Step 17 =====] \endgroup = \endgroup.
<| \begingroup \endgroup 
|> 
<| \begingroup \endgroup 
|> 

Step 17 was the last!
```

Of course, the effect of the `\AtEndDocument` command takes place, and there is a message "Bye!" at the end of the compilation

---

This example did not involve any complicated expansion.  For more fun in this direction, try to understand how the `l3fp` expression parsing works...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unravel}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\unravel { \fp_eval:n { sin(2pi/3) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

After some steps, I get the following shown on my terminal:

```
[===== Step 3334 =====] \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_to_decimal_dispatch:w 
|| \tex_romannumeral:D -48
|| \tex_romannumeral:D 
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_parse_after:ww 
|| \tex_romannumeral:D -48
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_parse_until_test:NwN 
|| \exp_after:wN \c_minus_one 
|| \tex_romannumeral:D -48
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_fixed_mul_after:wn 
|| \int_use:N 
|| \__int_eval:w -50000
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|| \int_use:N 
|| \__int_eval:w 499950000+05235*05235
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|| \int_use:N 
|| \__int_eval:w 499950000+05235*9877+9877*05235
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|| \int_use:N 
|| \__int_eval:w 499950000+05235*5598+9877*9877+5598*05235
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|| \int_use:N 
|| \__int_eval:w 499950000+05235*2990+9877*5598+5598*9877+2990*05235
|| \exp_after:wN \__fp_pack:NNNNNwn 
|> \int_use:N \__int_eval:w \c__fp_trailing_shift_int
|> +9877*2990+5598*5598+2990*9877+(5598*2990+2990*5598+\__fp_fixed_mul:nnnnnnnw
n
|> {0000}{0000}{05235}{9877}{05235}{9877}{0000}{0000};{\exp_after:wN
|> \__fp_sin_series_aux:NNnww \exp_after:wN \__fp_fixed_to_float:wN
|> \__int_value:w \if_int_odd... (223 chars)
```

(I obtained this by pressing `s3333` then enter twice).  What does all this mean?  Well, at some point during the expansion of `\fp_eval:n { sin(2pi/3) }`, TeX found `\exp_after:wN` (the LaTeX3 name for `\expandafter`), kept the next token, `\__fp_to_decimal_dispatch:w` for an expansion later, and expanded what follows.  What follows was `\tex_romannumeral:D` (next token in the part of the screen marked with `||`), which made TeX look for a number.  After expanding some tokens further, TeX found the (incomplete) number `` -`0 `` (equal to `-48`) which made it expand further, and so on.  The snapshot shown on the screen is taken at a time where TeX is 24 level deep in such nested expansions (all the tokens in the `||` part), and is going towards a 10th level since the last `\exp_after:wN` of the `||` part, after jumping over `\__fp_fixed_mul_after:wn`, hits `\int_use:N` (aka `\the`).  Needless to say, macros to perform floating point computations are a bit hard to follow.

In general, there can be three parts: `|>` denote tokens on input, that TeX has not yet seen, or that have been reinserted for instance after a macro expansion; `||` denote tokens that are stored for later; `<|` denote commands that have reached TeX's main loop (i.e., have gone through the whole machinery of expansion) and have an impact on typesetting.  Definitions are performed right away.

Implementing `unravel` was and is of course difficult, and I ended up having to very often rely on the TeX source code to find out how Knuth did various things.  In particular, the nesting of conditionals is a nightmare.  Those who know the source of TeX can probably recognise large traces of the influence in names such as `\@@_scan_int:` or `\@@_get_x_next:`.  Also, each primitive is given a command code and a character code, whose values follow precisely those of `pdfTeX`.

One direction I would like to explore is to output all the data to an XML file (or other) which could then be processed through various other tools, perhaps giving more interactivity.  Another interesting aspect would be to produce typeset content rather than on-screen diagnostic.  This would allow to differentiate more visually, for instance, between the pieces of the `||` region, and it would allow to also differentiate category codes through color, which can be important in some debugging tasks.  In the direction of producing less steps, I am wondering if giving a regular expression and performing silently expansions which pertain to commands matching with the regular expression would provide a useful filter.

Comment: This sounds useful. I would appreciate it if you could add a simple example (preferrably some simple yet untrivial plain tex example) such that the output of the tool relates to the input example?

Comment: This is an excellent attempt! Well done.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Oops, I just realized that my new example is LaTeX.  Do you have any idea what I could use as my plain TeX example (even `\newcount` leads to dozens of steps)?

Comment: @Bruno thanks for the new example! that's fine with me :)

Comment: Fantastic! Finally someone cracked it!

Comment: Wow, many thanks for that, @BrunoLeFloch - I had no idea until now this question had an answer! `:)` Sorry for the late accept - and many, many thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch This is potentially the biggest change in TeX usability since it was written! Thank you. The main thing this is missing IMO is the equivalent of `n` in a debugger: at any point, the user should be able to say "ok I understand the immediately next macro I see on screen, just do as many steps as it takes till I get to the one after that". Edit: Nevermind, I notice you have filed this as [issue #1 on Github](https://github.com/blefloch/latex-unravel/issues/1). :-)