# Try to use input and currfile together

Tags: input, currfile

I have a folder tree a little like this, "document.tex" is the root file, section1 is a folder

```
document.tex 
|--[section1]
|     |--index.tex
```

My document.tex  code is like that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile}

\newcommand{\insertIndex}[2]
{% 
   \input{#1#2/index} 
}
\begin{document}

\insertIndex{\currfiledir}{section1}

\end{document}
```

The command throw a error because it say

> section1/section1/index.tex" don't exist.

I try a lot and I don't understand why it duplicate the folder

If I view the string `#1#2/index` without the input the path is correct

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be very helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. I created the file `section1/section1/index.tex`, and it's content was properly displayed.  Have you any spaces in your directory/file names? Also, what does `index.tex` look like (i.e., does it have a preamble?).

Comment: the file I want to open is "section1/index.tex" but (I don't know why) he try to open "section1/section1/index.tex" it duplicate the  word "section1". In the file index.tex I simply write "hello world"

Comment: Opps, looked into it further and it is an expansion issue: So if you use `\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir}
\insertIndex{\CurrentFileDir}{section1}` things work correctly.  I am not very knowledgeable about expansion issues (just know enough to be dangerous :-)) so am hesitant to attempt to explain it.  But that should get you going until a proper answer comes along.

Comment: Also, you need to use `\newcommand{\insertIndex}[2]{%` (note the trailing `%`.  See for instance [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).

Comment: thanks! I work fine. You made my day =), I didn't know the "edef" command. Please submite your answer like a answer for approve it

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an expansion issue.  So first expand `\currfiledir` before using it:

```
\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir} 
\insertIndex{\CurrentFileDir}{section1}
```

### References:

- [What is "expansion"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158827/what-is-expansion)
- [A LaTeX log analyzer application (visualizing TeX expansion)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/a-latex-log-analyzer-application-visualizing-tex-expansion)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile}

\newcommand{\insertIndex}[2]{%
   \input{#1#2/index}%         <---- Note % here 
}
\begin{document}

\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir}%
\insertIndex{\CurrentFileDir}{section1}%

\end{document}
```