# How does \afterassignment work?

Tags: plain-tex

I've found the following code in another question:

```tex
\def\scan#1{\scanA#1*}
\def\scanA{\futurelet\next\scanB}
\def\scanB{\expandafter\ifx\next\space \expandafter\scanC \else \expandafter\scanE \fi}
\def\scanC{\afterassignment\scanD \let\next= }
\def\scanD{\scanE{ }}
\def\scanE#1{\ifx*#1\else \dosomething{#1} \expandafter\scanA \fi}
```

The effect is to convert a string like `ABC` into `\dosomething{A}\dosomething{B}\dosomething{C}`.

If `\let\dosomething=\uppercase`, then `\scan{Hello World!}` obtains `HELLO WORLD!`.

I understand when `\ifx\next\space` in `\scanB` gets `false`, it expands to `\scanE`, which captures the next unread token as its parameter and `\dosomething`.

However, when it gets `true`, it expands to `\scanC`. `\scanD` expands to `\scanE{ }` so that we may handle the spaces. But why the next `\scanA` will skip the space, and how `\afterassignment` and `\let\next=`  work?

===== update by OrthoPole =====

I think I've understood the process myself.

When the `\ifx` get `true`, the stream looks like `\futurelet·\next·\scanB·_·...` (`_` stands for a space token), and it expands to `\afterassignment·\scanD·\let·\next·=·_·_·...`. We see `\let` allows an optional space token, hence the first space after `=` will be omitted, and `\next` will be assigned the second space. After this assignment, `\scanD` will be expanded. Since the two spaces after `=` are absorbed by `\let`, we get `\scanD·...`.

Comment: By the way there's also the package `unravel` which allows you to walk through single steps by emulating parts of TeX. For TeX primitives I think it can be quite helpful. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/a-latex-log-analyzer-application-visualizing-tex-expansion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\afterassignment\cs` will reinsert `\cs` in the input stream as soon as the next assignment has been performed.

What's considered as an assignment? Setting the value of a register (but for box registers it's slightly more complicated); doing `\.def` where `.` stands for nothing, `g`, `x`, `char` and so on; doing `\let`.

Your case is the last one. Now the syntax for `\let` is

```
\let <cs><optional spaces><optional =><one optional space>
```

The `<optional spaces>` part is not interesting in your case, because you always have `\let\scanD`. More interesting is `<one optional space>`. In this case TeX does *no* expansion of the token following `=`, as witnessed by

```
\let\x=\space\message{abc}
```

that prints `abc` on the console and makes `\x` to be the same as `\space`.

Doing

```
\def\scanC{\afterassignment\scanD \let\next}
```

would fail if the token after `\scanC` is `=`, because it would be taken as part of the `\let` instruction, which isn't wanted. But also

```
\def\scanC{\afterassignment\scanD \let\next=}
```

would fail if the token after `\scanC` is an explicit space token, because it would be taken as `<one optional space>`.

You want instead to assign to `\next` the next token, so you need

```
\def\scanC{\afterassignment\scanD \let\next= }
```