# Dump command as readable text?

Tags: macros, verbatim, expansion, debugging

Is it possible to dump the expanded form of a command as text?

E.g. when I write a macro

```
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

I would want to define a macro `\mydump` such that

```
\mydump{\mytest{Hello World}}
```

creates a literal text `\mytest{Hello World}` in the output file.

When experimenting with custom macros, I sometimes run into rather unhelpful error messages. It would help a lot to be able to view level by level, how the problematic command is expanded.

I know that there are commands like `\show`, but those are command line oriented. Usually however I will be working in a LaTeX editor, that by default doesn't even show the log file, e.g. TeXStudio or Emacs with AUCTeX. So a more practical solution would be to put similar information into the output pdf file.

I tried to produce the needed output with something along the lines of combining `\verb` and `\expandafter`, but this gives no viable results (due to how LaTeX parses text into tokens and expands tokens as macros).

Comment: I think this could help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4784/36686

Comment: If you want to do any serious debugging of TeX code you need at least to read the log, if not to have the terminal output visible. Many TeX-focussed editors manage to combine showing the terminal stream with being GUIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two versions that give slightly different behavior, depending on what you really seek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\def\mydump#1{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\def\mydumplit#1{\detokenize{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mydump{\mytest{Hello World}}

\mydumplit{\mytest{Hello World}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, `\detokenize` has some limitations.  You can't have `%` in the argument, braces must be matched, etc.

Comment: all very modern and e-texy, not just `\meaning` ? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Two reasons come to mind.  Despite my age, I am a relative TeX newcomer (only a decade) and so am learning it backward: LaTeX first and then TeX.  But secondly, I seem to recall that `\meaning` comes with some leading gobbledygook that may need stripping.  For example, using `\def\mydumpold#1{\meaning#1}`, the result of `\mydumpold{\mytest{Hello World}}` is `\long macro:#1->\texttt {#1}Hello World` which may be more than the OP wants.